# Я передаю аргументы через bundle, но при получении даныe null. С чем это может быть связано?

Tags: android, kotlin

Доброе утро всем. Я получаю ответ от сервера и отправляю данные, которые пришли с сервера в фрагмент, в моем случае url, данные в запрос приходят и отображаются в логах, но при этом если я попробую отправить эти данные через bundle - они не придут к точке назначения. С чем это может быть связано?

> Код отправки данных

```
  viewModel.responseMainRequestCode.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            if (it.code == 302) {
                val response = gson.fromJson(it.body?.string(), MainRequestResponse::class.java)
                val location = response?.location
                val locationBundle = Bundle()
                locationBundle.putString("location", location)
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.chromeTabFragment)
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Gson location $location")
```

> Код получения данных

```
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val url = arguments?.getString("location")

        createChromeTab(url) // и на этой
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chrome_tab, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun createChromeTab(data: String?) {
        val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
        val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
        context?.let { customTabsIntent.launchUrl(it, Uri.parse(data)) // ошибка на этой строчке
            }
         }
       }
```

ошибка  null pointer exeption.

> Код ошибки

```
2021-05-17 11:38:07.887 7422-7422/com.example.test4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test4, PID: 7422
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:496)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:486)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:458)
    at com.example.test4.ChromeTabPage.ui.ChromeTabFragment.createChromeTab(ChromeTabFragment.kt:27)
    at com.example.test4.ChromeTabPage.ui.ChromeTabFragment.onCreateView(ChromeTabFragment.kt:16)
```

Comment: сначала данные нужно передать, потом в другой активити взять, и только потом уже из них брать нужную переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы бандл просто создаете, но не передаете никуда. Поправьте :

```
 NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.chromeTabFragment,locationBundle)
```

Comment: Спасибо) Просто пропустил этот момент))